# Outputting to Excel, how do I define different columns

Tags: php, excel, cells

I am outputting data from my DB to Excel (has to be .xls format), but how do I tell Excel to put the data in to a new cell or to start a new line?

```
/** Set the headers */
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=referrals.xls');

/** Output the column headers (We don't need the ID, so drop it) */
foreach($referrals[0] as $key => $value) :
    $array_keys[$key] = $key;
endforeach;
unset($array_keys['ID']);
echo join('???', $array_keys).'New row???';

/** Output the data */
foreach($referrals as $referral) : foreach($referral as $key => $value) :
        $referral_array[$key] = $value;
    endforeach;
    unset($referral_array['ID']);
    echo join('???', $referral_array).'New row???';
endforeach;
```

Comment: What Excel writer library are you using? And what does your data actually look like?

Comment: Not using a writer - literally grabbing my data from the DB in the form of arrays and then outputting it as above. I don't need anything pretty, just a dump of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try \t and \n,just like

```
echo join("\t", $array_keys)."\n";
```

\t for new column,\n for new row